# Multithreaded WebAssembly slower in browser than singlethreaded, why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, emscripten, webassembly

After not using Emscripten for a couple of years, I've recently discovered that it now supports compilation of multithreaded C++ code to WebAssembly. I've put together simple merge sort code that sorts 10 million floats (native code can easily sort more than that, but browsers seem to limit you to 1GB memory):

https://github.com/bsergeev/MtMergeSort

Surprisingly, while this code compiles to WebAssembly and runs in Chrome, the sort in the browser is getting slower as multiple threads are used (while single thread performance is, as expected, 1.5...2 times as slow as native one: native code 1.80 seconds, WebAssembly 3.1...3.3 seconds, and JavaScript 4.69 seconds):

[image: Comparison of x64 vs. WebAssembly vs. JavaScript]

Is the diminishing performance on multiple threads caused by browsers throttling down WebWorkers? But what is the point of multiple threads in WebAssembly then?

Comment: Resource contention can be a problem, preventing parallelization. Another common cause is the cost of thread management exceeding the time required to process the algorithm.

Comment: Side note: Links to offsite resources are frowned on. Stack overflow's goal is to create a repository of questions and answers to programming problems, and links rot, rendering the question useless to the programmers who follow. All information required to interpret the question MUST be included in the question.

Comment: When I run your code it immediately asserts: `Assertion 'l <= m && m <= r' failed.`  https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0373b0991417c4a0

Comment: Also, why is this code so complex? It seems like serious overkill

Comment: As far as I can see, https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e3b5f481bba4157 does the same thing, in half the code. (though only works when #threads is a power of 2)

Comment: Your 1, 2, 4, and 8 thread versions all work differently, so that's almost certainly related. And every version with 2+ threads blocks the main thread the whole time, and the 4+ versions make extra threads that are idle the whole time. That's probably not related, but it's not good practice either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out the culprit was allocation of left/right temporary arrays on different threads in `merge()`. As soon as I pre-allocated the temporary array on the main thread, WebAssembly scaled nicely:
[image: Multi-threaded performance]